# In the following sentence, shouldn't "family" take its plural form?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, kinship-terms, countable-nouns, collective-nouns

Here is an excerpt from IELTS OG.:

> For example, when my cousins were backpacking around the world, they were able to reassure their family and friends that....

I find the use of *family* in its singular form very strange, because obviously the author was talking about more than one family, since *cousins* have at least two families.

I suspect this has something to do with *family* being a collective noun, but I don’t think it is a good justification. It isn’t wrong to say *one family, two families*, is it?

Comment: It's still the same family even if they're only each other's cousins.

Comment: @tchrist 'Family' is ill-defined, polysemous. Nuclear family? ... Extended family (with or without Adam?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use *family* as a noncount noun, you should omit *their*:

> *When my cousins were backpacking around the world, they were able to reassure family and friends that . . .*

If those cousins of yours are siblings, they share the same family and your example is correct:

> *When my cousins were backpacking around the world, they were able to reassure their family and friends that . . .*

If two or more of said cousins are not siblings, they do not share the same family and you should pluralize *families*:

> *When my cousins were backpacking around the world, they were able to reassure their families and friends that . . .*

If you consider you and any of your cousins to be a part of one big happy family, you should . . . :

> *When my cousins were backpacking around the world, they were able to reassure their friends and our family that . . .*

Answer (score 0):

Family has some uncountable senses.  One of these is the sense "people who are family members."  This sense occurs commonly in the phrase "friends and family."

The sentence is correct as it stands.  It would also be correct to use "families" instead of "family."

Comment: It _might_ also be correct to use *families* in the plural, but this seems rather unlikely given that the referenced cousins of the narrator are almost certainly each other’s siblings or perhaps cousins, which means that they would all share the same family. Only if the two referenced cousins were each related only to the narrator and not to each other (because one was the narrator’s maternal cousin and the other their paternal cousin) might they have single shared family apart from the narrator themself. Seems unlikely to me.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with @TinfoilHat.

According to [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=their%20family%20and%20friends%2Ctheir%20families%20and%20friends%2Chis%20family%20and%20friends%2Chis%20families%20and%20friends&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctheir%20family%20and%20friends%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctheir%20families%20and%20friends%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20family%20and%20friends%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctheir%20family%20and%20friends%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctheir%20families%20and%20friends%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20family%20and%20friends%3B%2Cc0), *their families and friends* is more productive than *their family and friends*. In comparison, *his families and friends* has no results while *his family and friends* is very productive.

Therefore, I suspect that the IELTS writer was assuming that the cousins belonged to the same family when writing this sentence.